# php handler as cgi/suexec

Tags: php, apache, whm, suphp

in my phpinfo it is showing php handler as cgi/fastcgi but i want to change it to cgi/suexec.
i tried from whm php and suexec configuration and i found that suphp is default php haldler then why phpinfo is showing cgi/fastcgi as default handler.i want tochange to cgi/suexec as fastcgi is not working with php apc handler.

```
output of phpinfo
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

however whm shows

```
Configure PHP and SuExec
New Configuration

Option  Configured Value
Default PHP Version (.php files)    5
PHP 5 Handler   suphp
PHP 4 Handler   none
Suexec  on
```

Comment: Trust me, you **don't** want CGI/suphp. They are both horribly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want tochange to cgi/suexec as fastcgi is not working with php apc handler.

1. There is no cgi/suexec handler for php. There are only cgi, fastcgi and server specific modules. suexec is to change user who runs cgi process and can be applied to any other cgi interpreters, not only php.
2. CGI/FastCGI are handled by php from the same binary file, that's why it says `CGI/FastCGI`
3. APC works with FastCGI (under apache with `mod_fastcgi`, not `mod_fcgid`) better than CGI - in both cases it can be used to store and retrieve user data, but opcode cache will work only with properly configured FastCGI, in CGI cache will be destroyed after every request.

Comment: mod_fastcgi is not compatible with suphp